# Fastest way to count contiguously chars

Tags: count

I have a text string like:

> 33 P DDD AA 00 23

I've created a code that works well, but I'm searching for other methods to do that.

```
translate_dict = {
   ...
}    

result = []
i = 0

while i < len(t):
    counter = 1
    while i+counter < len(t) and t[i] == t[i+counter]:
        counter +=1
    result.append(translate_dict.get(t[i], t[i]) + str(counter))
    i += counter
    
return ''.join(result)
```

Comment: If the code works, this is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com Please also read its relevant help center pages like ['What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)'

Comment: Is "33 P DDD AA 00 23" the input? What's the output for that? Your code doesn't work at all, has a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible optimization:

```
def f2(t):
    res = []
    last = t[0]
    counter = 0
    duration = 0
    tr = translate_dict.get

    for c in t:
        if c == last:
            counter += 1
            continue
        res.append(tr(last, last) + str(counter))
        duration += counter
        last = c
        counter = 1

    res.append(tr(last, last) + str(counter))
    duration += counter

    return ''.join(res), duration
```

Shows ~ 2x improvement on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which is built into Python i.e., not an [*external*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1pQ9.png) library:

```
from itertools import groupby


def old_translation(t: str, translate_dict: dict[str, str]) -> tuple[str, int]:
  res = []
  i = 0
  duration = 0
  while i < len(t):
    counter = 1
    while i + counter < len(t) and t[i] == t[i + counter]:
      counter += 1
    res.append(translate_dict.get(t[i], t[i]) + str(counter))
    duration += counter
    i += counter
  return ''.join(res), duration


def new_translation(t: str, translate_dict: dict[str, str]) -> tuple[str, int]:
  translated = ''.join(
      translate_dict.get(k, k) + str(len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(t))
  duration = len(t)
  return translated, duration


translate_dict = {
    "H": "Ab",
    "I": "Bb",
    "J": "Cb",
    "K": "Db",
    "L": "Eb",
    "M": "Fb",
    "N": "Gb",
    "O": "A#",
    "P": "B#",
    "Q": "C#",
    "R": "D#",
    "S": "E#",
    "T": "F#",
    "U": "G#",
    "0": "A",
    "1": "B",
    "2": "C",
    "3": "D",
    "4": "E",
    "5": "F",
    "6": "G",
    " ": "P",
}
test_string = "33 P DDD AA 00 23"
print(f'{old_translation(test_string, translate_dict) = }')
print(f'{new_translation(test_string, translate_dict) = }')
```

**Output:**

```
old_translation(test_string, translate_dict) = ('D2P1B#1P1D3P1A2P1A2P1C1D1', 17)
new_translation(test_string, translate_dict) = ('D2P1B#1P1D3P1A2P1A2P1C1D1', 17)
```